# D3 not rendering simple bar chart in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, pug

I'm trying to create a simple bar chart from some dynamically generated data, but I can't get D3 to render the chart. Here's my jade layout:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  script(src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js")
  p Coverage: #{coverage}
  .chart
  script(type='text/javascript').
    var id =!{JSON.stringify(id)};
    var file="temp/"+id+".coverageHist.txt";
    var dataset = [];
    d3.tsv(file, function(data) {
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        dataset.push(d[0]);
      })
    });
    console.log(dataset);
    d3.select(".chart").selectAll("div")
      .data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .style("height", function(d) {
        var barHeight = d * 5;
        return barHeight + "px";
      });
```

And here's the rendered HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Results</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></head><body><h1>Results</h1><script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script><p>Coverage: 1.98612
</p><div class="chart"></div><script type="text/javascript">var id ="123c52299cd5cac9b858890be1e4271908bd93ac";
var file="temp/"+id+".coverageHist.txt";
var dataset = [];
d3.tsv(file, function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    dataset.push(d[0]);
  })
});
console.log(dataset);
d3.select(".chart").selectAll("div")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("height", function(d) {
    var barHeight = d * 5;
    return barHeight + "px";
  });</script></body></html>
```

Any ideas? I push the values to an array and then plot them using example code from the [Bar Chart tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7322386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `d3.tsv` is asynchronous, so you probably don't have any data in `dataset` when the rest of your d3 code runs.

Try putting everything from `console.log(dataset)` onwards in the callback for `d3.tsv`.